# How do you mark a field as nullable in a class for a SQLite table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, nullable

For columns that should be nullable in a class to be used for a SQLite database, can the column be marked as nullable by appending "?"

IOW, if I want "TimeOfTheSeason" to be nullable, is this the way to do it:

```
public class PlatypiRUs
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlatypusId { get; set; }
    public string PlatypusName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EOW { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeOfTheSeason { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I've been doing it, but I'm curious if there's a more "proper" way to do it, too.

Comment: I assume you are using codefirst?  If so, the question mark is working for me like you are showing.

Comment: After all, you can just try it out and see. PS: FluentNHibernate mapping works this way.

Comment: @Fauntleroy: I could if I was at the point of inserting records, but I'm just at the designing the classes/tables point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you can do that.

**DateTime cannot be used as a constant** but you could make it a **nullable type (DateTime?)** instead.

Give the **DateTime? a default value of null**, and if it is set to null at the start of your function, then you **can initialize it to any value** you want.

```
static void TestMethod(DateTime? dt = null)
{
    if (dt == null)
    {
        dt = new DateTime(1981, 03, 01);
    }

    //...
}
```

You can call it with a **named parameter** like this:

```
TestMethod(dt: new DateTime(2010, 03, 01));
```

And with the **default parameter** like this:

```
TestMethod();
```